# Opencv library using a STM32F407VGT6 ARM M4 PLATFORM

Tags: opencv, arm, cortex-m, robotics

I want to implement opencv library in a STM32F407VGT6 ARM M4 micro controller.Is that possible?? if not can you please tell me which platforms are best for use a opencv library?

I am developing a arrow detection robot and I plan to include image processing algorithms to detect the arrows. So I need a suitable platform to implement this scenario.I bought a STM32F407VGT6 ARM M4 micro controller. Is this micro controller suitable for my requirements ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a expert but after lots of googling i come to know that it's very difficult to port OpenCV on MCU . There are lots of limitation come with this. Due to following reasons it's not advisable to port OpenCV on MCU.

- Processing speed
- Limited RAM
- OpenCV use lots of Floating point operation, processing will very flow in MCU
- DMA
- Memory leakage
- Take very much effort to port as compared to port on raspberry PI, beaglebone Black etc.

One more option to use is readily available "OpenMV".

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many people implementing opencv library targeting ARM processors. Opencv has lots of FP operations and ARM processors with dedictaed FPUs will give you better performance.
Your board comes with a Cortex M4, it has hardware FPU, supports SIMD operations and support for CMSIS library. So it would work. However, if performance is critical, targeting the ARM A series is better.